# HTML/Javascript/CSS GUI for the development of desktop applications with python?

Tags: python, html, css, user-interface

I wonder if there's a python GUI like pyqt etc. which works purely with html and javascript for layouting desktop applications...

Do you know if there are projects like this? Does this make sense at all ;-) Or it it just me finding that a nice tool...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it were Python-based but had nothing to do with Python, would you really care if it wasn't Python based?

Anyways, yes, a project exists. A pretty big one too. It's called [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner). The project is maintained by Mozilla and is used for the GUI of every Mozilla program.

It features an XML-based syntax (XUL):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window id="main" title="My App" width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://myapp/content/main.js"/>

  <caption label="Hello World"/>
  <separator/>
  <button label="More >>" oncommand="showMore();"/>
  <separator/>
  <description id="more-text" hidden="true">This is a simple XULRunner application. XUL is simple to use and quite powerful and can even be used on mobile devices.</description>

</window>
```

And JavaScript:

```
function showMore() {
  document.getElementById("more-text").hidden = false;
}
```

You can even embed Python scripts, it seems, into your code: http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/no_wrap/tutorials/pyxulrunner/python_xulrunner_about.html

Comment: thats a very helpful answer...have you worked yet with XULRunner?

Comment: A few times, yes. Once you get the development environment setup (a few config files, directories, etc.), it's easy to work with. You can even include jQuery if you want! As usual, Mozilla has an awesome reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner

Comment: It's cross-platform too. The UI integrates perfectly with every OS. I still prefer PyQt4, though. It's just simpler for non-web tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention PyQt yourself, you could perhaps just create a simple GUI using these tools, with your entire application made up of a `QtWebKit` module. Then just point to some files you created locally, and browse them using your appliction? But, this would not be any different compared to using a normal browser, so there's not really any point in doing this in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

you could always use django, django templates support html, js, css, php etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer...i'm thionking of a not browser based solution...and therefore no server interaction etc.

Comment: yup didn't pay attention at first - in that case +1 to Blender's answer, looks promising